# symfony 1.4: two questions about sfDoctrineApplyPlugin (well, could be also considered as general questions)

Tags: symfony1

I have found in sfDoctrineApplyPlugin a template called applyAfter.php
that shows a message like "You have registered ok..." after the users apply for an account. It is called from the sfApply/apply action this way: "return 'After';" when the apply form is valid.

What kind of template is that? I never saw that way (return 'After';) of calling a template. Can someone give me info about that?

*Second question:* I show a layout with a language select when the the
apply form is printed. I wouldn't like to show that language select in
the page that shows the message "You have registered ok...". As the action
is the same in the both pages (sfApply/apply), what should i do to hide
the language select in the verification page?

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function returns the string 'After' to the caller.  The caller always seems to be as follows:  `$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('sfApplyResetRequest[%s]');`

So, the string 'After' is being used in conjunction with the setNameFormat function (which is part of the symfony libraries).  All it is doing, is setting the 'name' attribute for the form.  More information on this function [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormSchema#method_setnameformat).

For your second question, you could simply add an IF statement, to check to see if the current route is the one that you do not want to display the language select on.  If it isn't, then display the language select.

You can verify the current route with the following code:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getRouting()->getCurrentRouteName();
```

Comment: Thanks, but for second question I want to say that in both pages (the one with the form and the other one with the message "You have registered ok") the route is the same. So what can i do?

Comment: If the message is displayed after the form is posted, you can always do a  if (!isset($_POST['FormArgument'])) { //show lang select }